# Do I need threads in Hangman game?

Tags: c++, multiplayer, multithreading, linux

I wish to implement a simple multiplayer Hangman game with the rule slightly bended.

Rule:
All the players have to guess the alphabets in the word at the same time. Whoever player guesses a correct alphabet gets a point, and the player who puts the ending alphabet gets bonus points.
This will be about speed. The faster correct guess gets you ahead of others.

I intend to have a Qt/QML based GUI and the programming language will be C++. Platform will be Linux.

***I am thinking I'll need:

- One thread for handling user typing.

- Second thread for parallel display of what other players are typing.

- Third thread for parallel display of scores of every player on every player's screen.***

Do I need these 3 threads or I am barking the wrong tree?

Comment: Qt has built in async IO and frankly not having that would have been be the only real reason to use another thread

Comment: By the way: When you are searching for a project suitable for learning multithreading, try a simulation with a large number (several thousand) of interacting objects. You could have multiple threads and make each thread responsible for updating a fraction of these objects. That way you could experiment with the number of threads used for processing and see how it affects the performance.

Comment: @Byte56 I have edited question. Please have a look. Is it okay now?

Comment: Design decisions, for the most part, are opinion based. There's no most correct or best design. You only *need* threads if your technical requirements include them. You're the one that comes up with the technical requirements based on the features that need to be implemented and their performance requirements.

Answer (score 1):

When you can avoid threading, you should do so. Threading makes an application magnitudes more complex to develop, test and maintain. Any data exchange between threads can either lead to deadlocks or to race conditions which result in obscure and impossible to reproduce bugs.

There are APIs which make threading more manageable, like critical sections, mutexes or channel-based information exchange, but these present some pitfalls in themself and can be easily forgotten in situations where they should be used.

The only *good* reason to use threading is usually to parallelize very CPU-intense calculations. But not every problem can be parallelized easily. So even in that case you should t(h)read lightly and minimize any communication between threads.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion in the above comment, but the project needs to be somewhat useful too. Can you suggest a kind of game which involves multithreading without complex graphics?

Comment: @user462608 The thing I suggested in my comment to the question without complex graphic output :)

Answer (score 0):

Nowhere. No part of this game requires computations hard enough to justify the cost of maintaining multiple threads.

Comment: I think this guys wants to use this simple game to test his theorical knowledge

Comment: If that's what he wants he should say that, not ask something different. Although then we'd close it for *that* reason, it's not really asking about game development.